# More general than Measurable Space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

The space of Borel measurable functions on a topological space is a very general space. Are there other function spaces that are larger than measurable spaces but still contained in the space of all functions?

I.e. are there any other spaces (that are studied/noteworthy) that satisfy

$\text{set of continuous functions}\subset\text{measurable functions}\subset  ???\subset\text{set of all functions}$

Comment: This depends. What do you mean by space?

Comment: Set of functions. The set of measurable functions is very large. Is there any larger set (containing measurable functions) that is not identical to the set of all functions.

Comment: Well then the answer is trivially yes. Just take the set of all measurable functions (I'm guessing you have a specific measurable space in mind) and add some non-measurable functions.

Comment: Sorry what I meant is any space which is studied enough to be given its own name. That has some additional conditions which is not satisfied by all functions

Comment: Ok then what do you mean by larger? In terms of cardinality, or must it strictly contain the space of measurable functions? It also really depends on what measure space you are referring to. I recommend you add these details to your questions, or it will be closed for being unclear/too broad.

Comment: The inclusion you give is not true in all measure spaces. Are you talking about measurable functions on a topological space with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra